# How to run python test suite?

Tags: python, testing, cassandra

I have downloaded apache-cassandra-1.2.8-src inside that I have a directory called pylib which comes with a test suite. I need to execute the test suite to see if all the testcases pass or not. How do I run the python test suite?

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra tests are in the `test` directory. If you run `ant -p` you'll see there are different options for running the tests:

```
long-test                   Execute functional tests
pbs-test                    Tests PBS predictor
test                        Execute unit tests
test-clientutil-jar         Test clientutil jar
test-compression            Execute unit tests with sstable compression enabled
```

To run any of these you just need to do `ant <taskname>`.

Comment: I am able to run java test, but I want to run python test for "pylib" that comes with cassandra.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but none of the tests are running, I am getting the following output:
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s